# How to pass a grid's page size number to the controller

Tags: c#-4.0, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am working in Telerik Grid.

My code for paging in the grid is

```
   .Pageable(pg =>
   {
        pg.Style(GridPagerStyles.Numeric | GridPagerStyles.PageSizeDropDown);
   }
```

I need to remember the page size number when user changes and store in to a table. So, I need to pass the page size number from view to any action method in the controller. Provide me a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo mate,

Basically you can retrieve the page size on the client via the pageSize method of the Grid dataSource.
for example:

```
var pageSize = $(Grid).data().kendoGrid.dataSource.pageSize()
```

You can send this value easy to the server via the function check the example in the documentation:

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportreaddata-objectstringfunction